# React Native and WalletConnect (Uncaught Error: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNRandomBytes.seed'))

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile, expo, wallet-connect

I want to use WalletConnect on my ReactNative app. As the [WalletConnect](https://docs.walletconnect.com/quick-start/dapps/react-native) docs say, I'm using
`npx rn-nodeify --install --hack` (for introducing support for Web3) in an existing project.

Of course, I'm following these [docs](https://github.com/tradle/rn-nodeify) (which are indicated on the page of WalletConnect) but every time I run this app, I received

> Uncaught Error: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNRandomBytes.seed')

on screen. Is there anyway to solve this?

I´m using expo on android.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of nodeify command use this approach to integrate wallet connect library with bare CLI project.

Reference: https://github.com/WalletConnect/walletconnect-monorepo/issues/753

In package.json add following dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    . . . 
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.17",
    "@walletconnect/react-native-dapp": "^1.7.1",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "6.0.6",
    "react-native-randombytes": "^3.6.1",
    "react-native-svg": "9.6.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    . . . 
    "node-libs-react-native": "^1.2.1",
  },
```

Update metro-config.js

```
module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    extraNodeModules: require("node-libs-react-native")
  },
  . . . 
};
```

Add following statement in index.js

```
require("node-libs-react-native/globals.js");
```

Comment: Expo project configuration example is available here: https://github.com/draftbit/expo-walletconnect-demo